# Random Permutations

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, mapping, permutation

I am having trouble figuring out a decent way of randomly shuffling the elements in an `std::vector` and, after some operations, restoring the original order. I know that this should be a rather trivial algorithm, but I guess I'm too tired...

Since I am constrained to use a custom random number generator class, I guess I can't use `std::random_shuffle`, which doesn't help anyway, because I also need to preserve the original order. So, my approach was to create an `std::map` which serves as a mapping between the original positions and the random ones, like this:

```
std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> getRandomPermutation (const unsigned int &numberOfElements)
{
    std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> permutation;

    //populate the map
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
    {
        permutation[i] = i;
    }

    //randomize it
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
    {
        //generate a random number in the interval [0, numberOfElements)
        unsigned long randomValue = GetRandomInteger(numberOfElements - 1U);

        //broken swap implementation
        //permutation[i] = randomValue;
        //permutation[randomValue] = i;

        //use this instead:
        std::swap(permutation[i], permutation[randomValue]);
    }

    return permutation;
}
```

I am not sure that the above algorithm is a proper implementation for a random permutation, so any improvements are welcome.

Now, here is how I've managed to make use of this permutation map:

```
std::vector<BigInteger> doStuff (const std::vector<BigInteger> &input)
{
    /// Permute the values in a random order
    std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> permutation = getRandomPermutation(static_cast<unsigned int>(input.size()));

    std::vector<BigInteger> temp;

    //permute values
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < static_cast<unsigned int>(input.size()); ++i)
    {
        temp.push_back(input[permutation[i]]);
    }

    //do all sorts of stuff with temp

    /// Reverse the permutation
    std::vector<BigInteger> output;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < static_cast<unsigned int>(input.size()); ++i)
    {
        output.push_back(temp[permutation[i]]);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Something tells me that I should be able to use only one `std::vector<BigInteger>` for this algorithm, but, right now, I just can't figure out the optimal solution. Honestly, I don't really care about the data in `input`, so I could even make it non-const, overwrite it, and skip creating a copy of it, but the question is how to implement the algorithm?

If I do something like this, I end up shooting myself in the foot, right? :)

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < static_cast<unsigned int>(input.size()); ++i)
{
    BigInteger aux = input[i];
    input[i] = input[permutation[i]];
    input[permutation[i]] = aux;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Following Steve's remark about using "Fisher-Yates" shuffle, I changed my `getRandomPermutation` function accordingly:

```
std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> getRandomPermutation (const unsigned int &numberOfElements)
{
    std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> permutation;

    //populate the map
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
    {
        permutation[i] = i;
    }

    //randomize it
    for (unsigned int i = numberOfElements - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        //generate a random number in the interval [0, numberOfElements)
        unsigned long randomValue = GetRandomInteger(i);

        std::swap(permutation[i], permutation[randomValue]);
    }

    return permutation;
}
```

Comment: May I recommend bogosort it'll solve both your problems. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort

Comment: Why not save the state of the original list; and when done shuffling, just reassign your saved list to the shuffled one?

Comment: @Brendan I need to preserve only the order, not the contents of the list. This is part of a secure interactive protocol, which requires that the items in the list are randomly shuffled before doing interactions, and, after the protocol finishes, I need to restore the original order.

Comment: @RTS Could you please elaborate your idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for specific errors in your code:

```
permutation[i] = randomValue;
permutation[randomValue] = i;
```

is wrong. Observe that once you're finished, each value does not necessarily appear exactly once among the values of the map. So it's not a permutation, let alone a uniformly-distributed random one.

The proper means to generate a random permutation is what Tony says, use `std::random_shuffle` on a vector that initially represents the identity permutation. Or if you want to know how a shuffle is properly performed, look up "Fisher-Yates". In general, any approach that makes `N` random selections uniformly from `0 .. N-1` is doomed to failure, because that means it has `N^N` possible ways it can run. But there are `N!` possible permutations of `N` items, and `N^N` is generally not divisible by `N!`. Hence it's impossible for each permutation to be the result of an equal number of random selections, i.e. the distribution is not uniform.

> the question is how to implement the algorithm?

So, you have your permutation, and you want to re-order the elements of `input` in-place, according to that permutation.

The key thing to know is that every permutation is a composition of "cycles". That is to say, if you repeatedly follow the permutation from a given starting point, you come back to where you started (and this path is the cycle to which that starting point belongs). There may be more than one such cycle in a given permutation, and if `permutation[i] == i` for some `i`, then the cycle of `i` has length 1.

The cycles are all disjoint, that is to say each element appears in exactly one cycle. Because cycles don't "interfere" with each other, we can apply a permutation by applying each cycle, and we can do the cycles in any order. So, for each index `i` we need to:

- check whether we've already done `i`. If so, move on to the next index.
- set `current = i`
- swap `index[current]` with `index[permutation[current]]`. So `index[current]` is set to its correct value (the next element in the cycle), and its old value is "pushed" forward along the cycle.
- mark `current` as "done"
- if `permutuation[current]` is `i`, we've finished the cycle. So the first value of the cycle ends up in the spot formerly occupied by the last element of the cycle, which is right. Move on to the next index.
- set `current = permutation[current]` and go back to the swap step.

Depending on the types involved, you can optimize around the swaps - it may be better to copy/move to a temporary variable and the start of each cycle, then do a copy/move instead of a swap at each step of the cycle, and finally copy/move the temporary to the end of the cycle.

Reversing the process is the same, but using the "inverse" of the permutation. The inverse `inv` of a permutation `perm`, is the permutation such that `inv[perm[i]] == i` for each `i`. You can either compute the inverse and use the exact code above, or you can use code similar to the above, except move the elements in the opposite direction along each cycle.

An alternative to all that, since you implemented Fisher-Yates yourself -- as you're running Fisher-Yates, for each swap you perform record the two indices swapped in a `vector<pair<size_t,size_t>>`. Then you don't have to worry about cycles. You can apply the permutation to the vector by applying the same sequence of swaps. You can reverse the permutation by applying the reversed sequence of swaps.

Comment: Regarding the correction, actually, it works. I don't see how I could ever end up with any duplicates, no matter how many iterations I perform. Thanks for the "Fisher-Yates" (Knuth shuffle) suggestion. I remember now seeing it somewhere, but, it was really late last evening :)

Comment: @MihaiTodor: sorry, maybe I misread the code then, it was a bit late last night. My thought was, "suppose that `randomValue` just so happens to come out `0` every time". Then your permutation map will have all zeros as values, except that `permutation[0]` will be equal to `numberOfElements - 1`. Sorry if that's wrong.

Comment: The funny thing is that if `randomValue` turns out to be 0 every time, then my permutation will end up being the identity permutation. Remember that `permutation` is an `std::map`, not an `std::vector`. Now, I'm trying to comprehend your comment regarding the number of iterations, but it's giving me a hard time. Could you please provide a concrete example? I see it as just an issue regarding the number of iterations I perform. If I only do N iterations, then the maths says that I will not end up with a properly shuffled permutation, right?

Comment: @MihaiTodor: once you've switched to Fisher-Yates, the important point is that you do a random selection from `N`, then from `N-1`, and so on down to `2`. Then there are `N!` possible results for all the random selections put together, instead of `N^N`. Fisher-Yates ensures that every possible permutation is the result of precisely one random selection -- hence if the random generator is uniform then so is the shuffle.

Comment: "Remember that permutation is an std::map, not an std::vector" -- I don't see how this makes a difference. In your original code, if you do `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) { permutation[i] = 0; permutation[0] = i; }`, then you end up with a whole lot of zeros, no matter what kind of container `permutation` is.

Comment: Oh, shit! You are right... Sleepless nights are bad for coding. Thanks for that. Also, now I get the point about `N!`. Thanks a million!

Comment: That last paragraph about recording the Fisher-Yates swaps in a vector is pure brilliant, Steve. I would have never thought of it. You deserve a beer for this :) I am implementing it right now.

Comment: @Mihai: Btw, if your RNG works from a seed, then when permuting you can perform the swaps on `input` and do without `permutation`, that's exactly what `random_shuffle` does. When reversing the permutation, you can re-seed the RNG with the same seed, then record the swaps into a vector (or `std::stack`), and then replay them backwards on `input`. So *if* your RNG is reproducible, you only actually need to store the swaps briefly.

Comment: Good idea. That would require adding some means to reseed the random generator, but it's a nice feature. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're "randomising" a vector of n elements, you can create another `std::vector<size_t> index(n)`, set `index[x] = x` for `0 <= x < n`, then shuffle `index`.  Then your lookups take the form: `original_vector[index[i]]`.  The order of the original vector's never changed so no need to restore ordering.

> ...constrained to use a custom random number generator class, I guess I can't use `std::random_shuffle`...

Have you noticed this overload?

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class RandomNumberGenerator>
void random_shuffle ( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
                    RandomNumberGenerator& rand );
```

For details of how to wrap your random number generator with a compatible object, see http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomNumberGenerator.html

Comment: "set index[x] = x for 0 <= x < N" using the finally-exists-at-long-last `std::iota`, where available :-)

Comment: Oh, and even if you do have to change the original vector for some reason, you can use the index vector to do so, and use it again to reverse the process. This is done by following the cycles in the permutation defined by the index vector.

Comment: Unfortunately, since this would be an interactive protocol, I am not allowed to send the index vector along with the `original_vector`. If I were to use `std::random_shuffle`, I would need to wrap it up in some custom class (template), because I am unable to plugin my random number generator out of the box.

Comment: @Mihai: `random_shuffle` has an optional third argument to specify a source of random numbers.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, but it has this signature: `Pointer to unary function taking one argument and returning a value, both of the appropriate difference type (generally ptrdiff_t). The function shall return a value between zero and its argument (lower than this).` which implies that I need to wrap my custom generator in some function, and, honestly, I don't think it's worth the effort. I just converted my code to use the "Fisher-Yates" shuffle and I'm OK with this. All that remains is to see if I can improve the way I use my permutation map.

Comment: @MihaiTodor: that description means the same as "generate a random number in the interval [0, argument)", which is what your `GetRandomInteger` function already does.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, well, this example is simplified. GetRandomInteger returns an object, which I need to convert to integer, by calling a `ToUnsignedLong()` method on the object. I'm not sure how I can convince `std::random_shuffle` to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, depending on your application, if it is important that you have a truly uniformly distributed permutation, you cannot use any algorithm that calls a typical pseudo-random number generator more that once.

The reason is that most pseudo-random number generators, such as the one in clib, are Linear congruential.  Those have a weakness where they'll generate numbers that cluster in planes - so your permutations will not be perfectly uniformly distributed.  Using a higher-quality generator should get around that.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Alternatively, you could just generate a single random number in the range 0..(n!-1) and pass it to the unrank function for permutations.  For small enough n, you can store those and get a constant time algorithm, but if n is too large for that, the best unrank function is O(n).  Applying the resulting permutation is going to be O(n) anyway.

Comment: I am using the GMP library to generate random numbers, which implements the Mersenne Twister algorithm. Even though this is slow, I am supposed to pre-generate a cache of random numbers anyway, so I think this will suffice for now. The code is not intended to end up in production anyway. It's just for doing some cryptographic protocol simulations.

Answer (score 0):

Given a ordered sequence of elements `a,b,c,d,e` you first create a new indexed sequence: `X=(0,a),(1,b),(2,c),(3,d),(4,e)`. Then, you randomly shuffle that sequence and obtain the second element of each pair to get the random sequence. To restore the original sequence you sort the `X` set incrementally using the first element of each pair.

Comment: Well, yes, but this would involve changing my vector implementation from std::vector to std::map, which is not something that I want, because, after applying the permutation, I would have to clone its contents in a temporary `std::vector`

Comment: The answer works nicely however if you make it `(0,&a),(1,&b),(2,&c),(3,&d),(4,&e)`, storing pointers to the elements rather than the elements themselves, assuming that the vector of elements is not altered in the interim (which would invalidate the pointers).